# Wordpress/MovableType: How does Lifehacker implement their comment system?

Tags: wordpress, comments, blogs, movabletype

I really like how [Lifehacker.com](http://www.lifehacker.com) (and `Gawker.com`) implements their comment system.

I believe, but am not certain, they use **Movable Type** as the platform for their blog.

What I like about their comment system is that it's a simple open text field and once you click "Share" it then asks you to register.

*Question*: Anyone know how to accomplish this same functionality with either **Wordpress** or **Movable Type**?

Comment: That sounds awful. Does it really let people spend five minutes composing a comment before it reveals that they have to hand over their email address?

Comment: It's not that bad, it simply just asks for your email address and that's it. It's a better UI experience.

Comment: I'm with David. So far, every time I've encountered a site that pretends I can comment and then demands more info when I try to submit the comment, I've closed the page and not come back. What exactly is better about having to submit two forms to post a comment instead of one? If you require the email, get it up front.

Comment: The Wordpress *almost* accomplishes this with the Prologue. It's close, but not exactly what's described above.

Answer (score 1):

The Gawker blogging network (of which lifehacker and gizmodo are part) use their own custom blogging platform ([Pingdom blog post](http://royal.pingdom.com/2009/01/15/the-blog-platforms-of-choice-among-the-top-100-blogs/) at beginning of last year)

If you want users to register before they leave comments, go to Admin > Options > General and check "users must register to leave comments" (or at least I think that's the right path, I'm doing it from memory)